# Function for computing the number of samples needed for a reliable estimate?

Tags: multiple-regression, linear-model, least-squares

For an ordinary least squares linear regression we have

$$y = X\beta + \varepsilon$$

where $y$ and $\varepsilon$ are $n × 1$ vectors, and $X$ is an $n × p$ matrix of regressors.

Is there a function for computing what $n$ should be in order to obtain a statistically reliable estimate of $y$ for various values of $p$?

What if we assume there is at least some collinearity among the regressors?

Also, is there a function that describes the relationship between the statistical reliability of the estimate with respect to $p$ assuming the number of samples $n$ is held constant?

Comment: If you have some data already then you can create a prediction interval of future observations and calculate the $n$ which gives you a desired width. http://reliawiki.org/index.php/Multiple_Linear_Regression_Analysis#Confidence_Interval_on_New_Observations

Comment: Look at PASS version 14 (www.ncss.com) for which multiple linear regression power is essentially based on the R-squared of multiple variables.   Something also tells me from memory that Cohen's effect size textbook addressed multiple R2 and power.